# Make wp_dropdown_categories into a variable that persists until changed?

Tags: categories

User selects category1 from wp_dropdown_categories, if user clicks on tag2 any point after, they only see posts from category1 with tag2, not all posts with tag2.

Is there a way to store the chosen category as a variable and use that to filter all content, until that variable is changed or removed?

Comment: Can you provide a little context? What's your current code look like?

Comment: Currently I just have the wp_dropdown_categories, really wasn't sure where to go with it from there, I just threw together a pastebin with pseudocode here, http://pastebin.com/CqiEXJZg

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `selected` argument:

```
wp_dropdown_categories( array(
    'show_option_all' => 'All Deployments',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'show_count' => true,
    'selected' => get_query_var( 'cat' ),
));
```

**Update:** Hook onto the `tag_link` filter & add the current category (if applicable):

```
add_filter( 'tag_link', 'wpse_71874_tag_link_category_context' );

function wpse_71874_tag_link_category_context( $link ) {
    if ( is_category() && $cat_id = get_queried_object_id() )
        $link = add_query_arg( 'cat', $cat_id, $link );
    return $link;
}
```

Comment: Well that works as long as I only bounce from category to category, here's the catch. Say I have two posts, one is category1/tag1, the other is category2/tag1. If I'm looking at the post from category1 and click on it's tag (tag1) I only want to see category1/tag1 posts but instead I see all posts with tag1.

Comment: Check my update.